# Extended binomial distribution

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to implement the extended binomial density function with support on c( 0 : (floor(N) + 1)), but I'm running into (I think) precision issues, as running:

```
########################
#---DENSITY FUNCTION---#
########################
debinom <- function(k, n, p, sum) {
    if (k <=  n) {
  return( choose(n, k) * p^k * (1-p)^(n-k) )
  } else {
    return (1.0 - sum)
    }
}#END: pebinom

##########################################
#---CUMULATIVE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION 2---#
##########################################
pebinom <- function(x, n, p) {

  # point mass at 0
  totalDensity = cumProb = debinom(0.0, n, p, 0.0)

  k = 0
  while (k <= (x)) {
    density2 = debinom(k, n, p, totalDensity)
    totalDensity = totalDensity + density2
    cumProb = cumProb + density2
    k = k + 1
  }

  k = k + 1
  density = debinom(k, n, p, totalDensity)
  cumProb = cumProb + density * (x - k)

  return (cumProb) 
}#END: debinom

############
#---TEST---#
############
for (i in 0:10) {
x = i + runif(1)
cat(x, " ", pebinom(x, 100, 0.1), "\n")
}
```

gives a negative probabilities for tail values.

## EDIT

I have changed, and mostly simplified the routines along the comments and answers I've received:

```
#########################################
#---PROBABILITY DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION---#
#########################################

debinom <- function(k, n, p) {

if (k <=floor(n)) {

  return( choose(n, k) * p^k * (1-p)^(n-k) )

  } else if(k == (floor(n)+1)) {

    cumProb = 0.0
    for(i in 0 : floor(n)) {
      cumProb = cumProb + debinom(i, n, p)  
    }

    return (1.0 - cumProb)

    } else {

  return(0.0)
    }

}#END: pebinom

########################################
#---CUMULATIVE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTION---#
########################################
pebinom <- function(x, N, P) {

cumProb = 0
for(i in 0 : (floor(x)) ) {
 cumProb = cumProb + debinom(i, N, P)
}

return(cumProb)
}
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of the language you are using but it seems to me that the first argument `k` of `pebinom` should be an integer and not a floating point number as in `totalDensity = cumProb = pebinom(0.0,n,p,0.0)`.  Also, it seems like you are including the point mass at $0$ twice in `totalDensity` and `cumProb`, once in the initialization and again when you call `pebinom` with `k` equal to $0$.

Comment: Could you please supply a definition of the "extended binomial density"?  Your function `pebinom` doesn't fit the bill because it does not define a valid probability distribution unless `sum` is identically 1.

Comment: I have edited the code to comply with naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems several problems here

First, what is "extended binomial distribution". Will you please give some reference to it? I'm aware about extended (aka truncated) negative binomial distribution, but here it seems it's not the same. Looking into pebinom() it looks like you're just looking for ordinary binomial distribution.

Second, the "else" case in pebinom looks completely bogus - if pebinom is a density function, when it should integrate (wrt counting measure) to one. Thus for k > n pebinom should return 0.

Next, couple of other problems: you're including the point mass at 0 twice, variables totalDensity and cumProb denotes the same thing.

Now, let's proceed to the problem of the negative values. It seems you're wanting to interpolate stuff if you x is between k and k + 1. In fact, you shouldn't do this, since the density wrt counting measure is zero between integer points. Anyway, your problem is that you're trying to interpolate at wrong points. Look, after your loop k is already > x, so, you have to interpolate between the points k-1 and k. Instead, you increase the k, calculate the density there and try to interpolate on a wrong interval, thus:

1. You should not increase the k after the loop (just remove that line)
2. You should multiply the density with (x - k + 1), not with x - k

PS: Get rid of loops, R perfectly allows you to write vectorized code.

Comment: We denote almost binomial distribution supported on $0,...,\left\lfloor N\right\rfloor +1$
by:

$P\{X=k\}=\begin{cases}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
k
\end{array}\right)p^{k}(1-p)^{N-k} & k=0,...,\left\lfloor N\right\rfloor \\
1-\underset{i=1}{\overset{\left\lfloor N\right\rfloor }{\sum}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
i
\end{array}\right)p^{i}(1-p)^{N-i} & k=\left\lfloor N\right\rfloor +1
\end{cases}$

Now $EBin(N,p)$ has a density equal to $P\{X=k+1\}$ for $x\in[k,k+1)$
with point mass of $P(X=0)$ at $0$, thus is supported on $[0,...,\left\lfloor N\right\rfloor +1]$

Comment: @fbielejec  Since $N$ is apparently _not_ an integer, what is meant by $\binom{N}{k}$?  Something to do with Gamma functions such as $\Gamma(N+1)/\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(N-k+1)$?  If so, how does your `pebinom` compute this since you seem to be using `choose (n,k)` which presumably has integer arguments and returns the binomial coefficient?

Comment: choose(n,k) is defined for all real numbers n and integers k. For $k\geq1$
it is defined as $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-k+1)}{k!}$

Comment: @fbielejec: Ok, thanks for the definition. You random variable is definitely discrete, thus it cannot have "density equal to P{X=k+1} for x∈[k,k+1)" since your variable cannot have, for example, value of 1/2. The density is zero between integer points, all you have is just a bunch of atoms.

Thus, the cdf is (as usual) just sum(pebinom(0:floor(x), N, p)) (note that you broken the naming conventions, your pebinom should really be debinom, it's a density wrt counting measure, and debinom should be pebinom).

Comment: @Anton Korobeynikov: I have added a new routines to my previous post, mostly following Your comments. If this works out as expected I will vectorize code for speed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your program.  First, you set

`totalDensity = cumProb = debinom(0.0, n, p, 0.0)`

which sets `totalDensity` and `cumProb` to $(1-p)^n$.
The first iteration of your loop (executed with `k = 0`)
adds `debinom(0, n, p, totalDensity)` (which *also* has
value $(1-p)^n$) to both `totalDensity` and `cumProb`
and so now `totalDensity` and `cumProb` both contain
$2(1-p)^n$.  Thus, after the last iteration of the loop,

- `totalDensity` and `cumProb` have value
  $$(1-p)^n + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
  where the relationship, if any, between $x$ and $n$ is unspecified,
  but I am assuming that $x = n$.  `totalDensity` and `cumProb`
  **should** have value equal to the sum but you have included an extra
  $(1-p)^n$.  Thus, it is possible that `totalDensity` and `cumProb` might have 
  value greater than $1$.
- `k` had value $\lfloor n \rfloor$ at the beginning of the last
  execution of the loop, and since `k` is incremented at the end of the loop,
  it has value $\lceil n \rceil$ upon exit from the loop.

You now increment `k` again to $\lceil n \rceil + 1$ and call 
`debinom(`$\lceil$`k`$\rceil$`, n, p, totalDensity)` which returns
`1 - totalDensity` since the first argument of `debinom`
is larger than the second, and this could well be a negative number.
Then you multiply `density` by `x-k` which could well be a negative number
if `x` is the same as `n`.

As a general comment,
$$\binom{x}{k} = \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-k+1)}{k!}$$
is positive for $0 \leq k \leq \lceil x \rceil$ and then
alternates in sign as  $k$ increases beyond $\lceil x \rceil$,
and this might be a source of the negative probabilities being found
at the tails.